# How to check you have landed on one of several pages in Geb

Tags: groovy, cucumber, geb

I'm new to Groovy and testing a website with reasonably complex workflows using Geb/Cucumber.

I have a set of product pages represented by page classes Prod1Page, Prod2Page and Prod3Page. They share certain characteristics that can be tested by the same code.

I want to write a ProductPage page class along the lines of:

```
class ProductPage extends Page {
    ...
    static at = {...}
    ...
}
```

so that

```
Given(~/.../) {
    ...
    at ProductPage
    ...
}
```

would pass if any of the following were true:

```
at Prod1Page
at Prod2Page
at Prod3Page
```

In case it's not clear my goal is to avoid duplicating the details of Prod[1-3]Page classes somewhere else.

Thanks for any insights,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProductPage`'s at checker just assert that the common HTML elements between all `Prod#Page`s are available. For example, if all ProdPages have a `<div id="productContainer">` element then you can put the following in your `ProductPage` class:

```
class ProductPage extends Page{

static at = { $("#productContainer").displayed }

...
}
```

Now in your test you can call `at ProductPage` and it will assert true if that common element is currently available on the WebDriver's DOM; and you will know that you are on one of the ProdPages.